# LocationService not retrieving location using only Network

Tags: android, gps, location-services

I have re-read the whole [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) and as I understand, this API intelligently fuses the providers to give you an accurate result.

> The Fused Location Provider intelligently manages the underlying location technology and gives you the best location according to your needs.

To my understanding, it will use **Network and WiFi and GPS** to give you a location. Now it is only logical to assume if one of those 3 is unavailable, it will use the remaining 2.

My problem is I'm testing my app to get `Location` when both **WiFi and GPS** are off. That will leave **Location Service** with the *network provider* only. But I'm getting Latitude and Longitude = `0.0`

Long story short, either way I'm wrong in assuming that it will work relying only on network (no GPS, no WiFi) or there is something else I don't know or haven't read yet. Which of this 2 is my issue?

**PS:** my `LocationRequest` configuration is set to `setInterval(30000)` to `setFastestInterval(60000)` (30 and 60 seconds respectively, for each update.

Comment: Maybe your network provider doesn't provide location information...?

Comment: I just tried a couple of things and I believe I'm mixing things up. I thought if **Location** was turned off (in phone Settings), I could get location information from network, but it seems I can't. I kinda thought Location on/off meant GPS on/off. So it seems I can't at all. Am I wrong?

Comment: Probably. If you turn Location off, then... well, you won't get any locations. The FLP will work out your location if GPS is unavailable (i.e. indoors) and/or Wifi is off or unavailable. That's not to say you wouldn't be able to get the tower-id and resolve it to a location with the aid of an external database like location-api and similar.